# @ character in Android - What is the meaning of the at-character?

Tags: android, kotlin

What meaning has the @-character in Android?

For example:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

Or:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/showDefault"
```

Or:

```
this@MainActivity
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first two examples, the `@` means "this is a reference to a resource". `@color/colorPrimary` is a reference to a color resource named `colorPrimary`. `@+id/showDefault` is a reference to an ID resource named `showDefault`, with the `+` sign meaning "if this ID is not already declared in this file, I am declaring it now".

Your third example is not from Android. It is programming language syntax. In your case, it is specifically from Kotlin. `this@MainActivity` is [a qualified `this`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified), used in cases where you have inner classes or other nested object scopes, and you need to indicate which `this` is really the one that you want.